# Как сделать перенос строки после тега </br> и удалить все html-теги регулярным выражением

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Данные приходят в следующем виде

```html
"<p>-Text1<br/>-Text2<br/></p>"
```

Как при помощи регулярного выражения можно после каждого br сделать перенос строки и удалить все теги, чтобы получить чистый текст с переносами?

Comment: А решение должно быть обязательно с помощью регулярных выражений?

Comment: Ну, если есть какие-либо еще варианты, то можно попробовать без регулярных выражений

Comment: Попробуйте с помощью `innerHTML` и `innerText` убрать все теги. Заменить `<br/>` на переносы строки, надеюсь, вы сможете (подумайте о функции `split`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
console.log('<p>-Text1<br/>-Text2<br/></p>'.replace(/(<br\s?\/>)|(<.*?>)/g, (match, p1) => p1 ? '\n' : ''));
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно было просто `/<br\/>/` но мало-ли, всякое бывает)))

`\s` — space, пробельный символ

`?` — означает 0 или 1 совпадение. Т.е. символа там может и не быть.

Флажок `i` — insensitive (будет заменять и br, и BR)

Флажок `g` — global, не будет останавливаться на одной, а до конца заменит все совадения.

```js
let str = '<p><span>Контрольный спан...</span><img src="контрольная картинка"><br>1<br>2</br>3<BR/>4< / br>5<br />6</p>';

function removeHTMLtags(str){
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = str.replace(/<\s?\/?\s?br\s?\/?\s?>/ig, "\n");
  return div.textContent;
}

console.log( removeHTMLtags(str) );
```

Comment: Да, в целом ваше решение делает то, что нужно, только оставляет тег <p>, но я решил задачу следующей регуляркой str.replace(/(\<(\/?[^>]+)>)/g, "\n")

Comment: @DmitriyV. Упс. Обновил ответ) Там регулярка пригодилась только для br... всё остальное можно отбросить через textContent )

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему следующим регулярным выражением:

```html
str.replace(/(\<(\/?[^>]+)>)/g, '\n')
```

Comment: ваш регексп заменяет любой открывающий и закрывающий тег на \n, а ТС просил "при помощи регулярного выражения можно после каждого br сделать перенос строки"

Comment: @nörbörnën он и есть ТС :D